# Set Spotify as the source for song titles instead of iTunes

Tags: macos, itunes, spotify

A *lot* of applications say something to the effect of "get the current song title from iTunes for your status", so is there any way to have those pull from Spotify instead of iTunes?

I'm willing to jump through a *few* hoops, and I'm a software developer so I don't mind some hacks, but I would love to be able to have those apps pull from my Spotify playlist instead of iTunes (who even downloads music anymore? Savages! :p )

Comment: Let me see if I can solve this! :-)

Comment: This is now possible as Spotify is applescripted and has a api

Answer (score 1):

What application are you interested in exactly?

One workaround could be to make Spotify scrobble to Last.fm (in preferences), and then get the song title from Last.fm. Iirc, there is a plugin for Adium that does this. Caveat: there'll be some delay in the updates when using this method.

Comment: So, I'll have to run Spotify, Last.FM, Adium ... Yeah, I think I'll pass. ~~ Nicely what I would like to see happen is the media player experience on OSX have the "default applications" that Windows has, and provide hooks from the OS, so that when I press the play button on my soft-keys, the Spotify app starts playing, even if it doesn't have the focus. And then the sort of thing I ask above would be handled already. ~~ Passed on Adium long ago in favor of Messages + Skype, and I haven't signed up for a Last.FM account _yet_ so I think that would be a silly reason now...